# Auto php echo for HTMl special characters

Tags: php, html

I'm developing a php web app in Portuguese, but when I want to echo some word with special character, like:

ç õ â é

The echo prints the html equivalent. Is there any function that convertsthe special characters to their html equivalent?

Tks

Comment: "The echo prints the html equivalent" What is the html equivalent? Could you post some sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use htmlentities()

http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

what is your page encoding? utf-8? and what is your file's encoding?
try to set the file's encoding to UTF-8 without BOM
and set page encoding to utf-8

Comment: If you need to ask for clarification, use a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I can't really find the button "comment". I was really searching for it but I just can't find it.

Comment: Whoops, my bad -- you only have 31 reputation at the moment.  You'll get comment access when you hit 50.  Sorry for chastising your for not doing something you can't actually do. >.>